# Alternative to SQL Cross apply because of performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sqlxml, cross-apply

I am stuck in a bit rut. I have an xml and in SQl server. I want to get all the values of FBC separated by commas.

Name of the table is Table1. Name of the column in which xml is stored is FareDetails. BookingID and ID are other columns of Table 1.

```
SELECT
    (PTSD.PSTDNode.value('(FBC)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1024)')  + ',') [text()]
FROM
    [Table1]
    CROSS APPLY [FareDetails].nodes('/AirFareInfo/PTSDPFS/PTSD') PTSD(PSTDNode)
WHERE
    [BookingID] = 123
ORDER BY
    [AirTraveler].ID ASC
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

But I have million records in the DB and this is taking a huge toll on performance.

The xml:

```
<AirFareInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IPFA="false">
  <PT>Flight</PT>
  <FPMID>0</FPMID>
  <PTID>1</PTID>
  <FS>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </FS>
  <TF>
    <CID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Value>0</Value>
  </TF>
  <VF>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VF>
  <VD>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VD>
  <VCR xsi:nil="true" />
  <VC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VC>
  <VFC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VFC>
  <VST />
  <VIT />
  <AAPFVDR xsi:nil="true" />
  <CC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </CC>
  <D>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>514.15</Value>
  </D>
  <PD>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </PD>
  <EBF>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </EBF>
  <CST>
    <DL>
      <ATRID>13</ATRID>
      <OB>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>74.04</Value>
      </OB>
      <OC>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OC>
      <OS>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OS>
      <OF>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>50.83</Value>
      </OF>
      <OP>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OP>
      <C>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </C>
      <IBF>false</IBF>
      <D>2014-06-09T14:57:53.521Z</D>
    </DL>
  </CST>
  <CIT />
  <CRMR xsi:nil="true" />
  <CRM>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </CRM>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Arrival (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>75.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Passenger Service Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>146.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Departure (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>1681.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Cute Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>50.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Government Service Tax">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>151.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Arrival (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>833.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Passenger Service Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>1132.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Departure (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>76.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Government Service Tax">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>148.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
      <ACD RBD="" ACCID="1" MCT="Super Sale Fare(AP)" INC="false" />
      <ATSID xsi:nil="true" />
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
      <ACD RBD="" ACCID="1" MCT="Super Sale Fare(AP)" INC="false" />
      <ATSID xsi:nil="true" />
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <RuleDetails>
    <TRS xsi:nil="true" />
    <PP xsi:nil="true" />
    <II xsi:nil="true" />
    <LTD xsi:nil="true" />
  </RuleDetails>
</AirFareInfo>
```

Output in this case should be AP,AP. How to improve the performance?

Comment: Your xml is not in correct format,not able to declare with xml type.read this header "Nodes() Method Application and Efficiency" https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/

There is one more thing in xml manipulation,but not ale to recall that.

Comment: *But I have million records in the DB*... Reading values **within XML** for millions cannot be fast... But your are using `WHERE [BookingID] = 123`. Are you filtering this call to a few records? Is the number of `<PTSDPFS>` fix (in this case two) or `1:n`? Is the content *within* this node fix or might this be `1:n` somewhere? Is this a *one-time-action* or something you've to do regularely? You might use a trigger. to maintain a side table with values you want to search for.

Comment: Where is `AirTraveler.ID` coming from?

Comment: @Shnugo : <PTSDPFS> can be 1 to n
The code Ive mentioned is in a UDF which is being called from sp.

Comment: The performance might be from here: *The code Ive mentioned is in a UDF which is being called from sp* Calling a (scalar?) UDF from a SP tends to show horrible performance. Did you check my answer? If you can call this *inlined*, it should perform much better...

Comment: @– Shnugo : That UDF is scalar valued function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in my comment, the best answer depends on many factors I don't know. Just as a quick shot you might try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FareDetails.query(N'data(/AirFareInfo/PTSDPFS/PTSD/FBC)').value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(100)'),' ',',')
FROM Table1
WHERE BookingID=123
```

XML method `data()` returns all found `text()` separated by a blank (regretfully one cannot change this). This works, as long as your text within `<FBC>` does not contain a blank it self.

Comment: This answer is giving output : AP,A instead of AP,AP

Comment: @PiyushSing I tried this and I got the correct result. Maybe this is cut somewhere (variable to small, other function...)

Comment: Hi @shnugo ,  when we have duplicate bookingid's in the table then it is failing .e.g BookingID 123 is coming 4 times in the table and in FareDetails(xml) FBC has values a ,b , c, d corresponding to 4 xml's.
The output should be a,b,c,d for all the 4 BookingID .
Currently output is a, for 1st entry , b, for 2nd entry , c, for 3rd entry  , d, for 4th entry . Please assist.

Comment: @PiyushSing Please avoid chameleon questions! The initial question did not tell anything about more than one record per BookingID. In this case you'd have to read all these lines like above and concatenate them to one single answer. But what about duplicate values? This is a completely new question! If my answer solves this issue. Please accept it (check below the vote counter) and start a new question. Please **reduce** your sample to the needed minimum!

Comment: Thanks for this solution , I have posted the separate question , please have a look at it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777070/get-comma-separated-values-from-an-xml-in-sql

Comment: Need your assistance on this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063593/sql-server-issue-in-exists-query-replace-with-joins)