# Get comma separated values from an xml in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlxml, sqlperformance, cross-apply

I am calling Scalar UDF from a stored procedure to get a column value. Inside the scalar UDF I have an xml and I have to get the comma separated values of a particular node. I used Cross apply but it caused huge performance bottleneck because stored procedure is actually used to fetch reports.

There is a table [Traveler] which has a field ID, BookingID(can be duplicate) and FareDetails. Inside the FareDetails we are storing the xml.

The logic inside UDF is as follows :
1st Solution , Using Cross Apply :

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBookingInfo] (@BookingID bigint, @InfoID smallint) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024) AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @InfoCSV VARCHAR(1024)

            --
            -- Fare Basis: InfoID = 1
            --
            IF @InfoID = 1
            BEGIN

                    SELECT @InfoCSV = (SELECT
                        (PTSD.PSTDNode.value('(FBC)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1024)')  + ',') [text()]
                    FROM
                        [Traveler]
                        CROSS APPLY [FareDetails].nodes('/AirFareInfo/PTSDPFS/PTSD') PTSD(PSTDNode)
                    WHERE
                        [BookingID] = @BookingID
                    ORDER BY
                        ID ASC
                    FOR XML PATH (''))

                IF @InfoCSV IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@InfoCSV) > 0
                    SET @InfoCSV = LEFT(@InfoCSV, LEN(@InfoCSV) - 1)
            END

            RETURN @InfoCSV
```

2nd solution , without cross apply :

```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBookingInfo] (@BookingID bigint, @InfoID smallint) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024) AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @InfoCSV VARCHAR(1024)

            --
            -- Fare Basis: InfoID = 1
            --
            IF @InfoID = 1
            BEGIN

                  SELECT @InfoCSV = (SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(FareDetails.query(N'data(/AirFareInfo/PTSDPFS/PTSD/FBC)').value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(100)'),' ',',')
        FROM [Traveler]
        WHERE
                [BookingID] = @BookingID)

                IF @InfoCSV IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@InfoCSV) > 0
                    SET @InfoCSV = LEFT(@InfoCSV, LEN(@InfoCSV) - 1)
            END

            RETURN @InfoCSV
```

The 2nd solution is saving lot of time , but when we have duplicate booking ID's then it is not concatenating all the values of FBC .
e.g. :
1)If BookingID is unique and we have FareDetail xml as follows then output should be  be AP,AP
2)If BookingID is not unique(coming twice) and we have FareDetail xml as follows then output should be  be AP,AP,AP,AP corresponding to both BookingID.
The xml is as follows :

```
<AirFareInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IPFA="false">
  <PT>Flight</PT>
  <FPMID>0</FPMID>
  <PTID>1</PTID>
  <FS>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </FS>
  <TF>
    <CID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Value>0</Value>
  </TF>
  <VF>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VF>
  <VD>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VD>
  <VCR xsi:nil="true" />
  <VC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VC>
  <VFC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </VFC>
  <VST />
  <VIT />
  <AAPFVDR xsi:nil="true" />
  <CC>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </CC>
  <D>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>514.15</Value>
  </D>
  <PD>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </PD>
  <EBF>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </EBF>
  <CST>
    <DL>
      <ATRID>13</ATRID>
      <OB>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>74.04</Value>
      </OB>
      <OC>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OC>
      <OS>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OS>
      <OF>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>50.83</Value>
      </OF>
      <OP>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
      </OP>
      <C>
        <CID>2</CID>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </C>
      <IBF>false</IBF>
      <D>2014-06-09T14:57:53.521Z</D>
    </DL>
  </CST>
  <CIT />
  <CRMR xsi:nil="true" />
  <CRM>
    <CID>2</CID>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </CRM>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Arrival (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>75.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Passenger Service Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>146.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Departure (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>1681.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Cute Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>50.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Government Service Tax">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>151.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Arrival (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>833.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Passenger Service Fee">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>1132.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="User Development Fee - Departure (UDF)">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>76.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <TL ATC="Tax" PC="" DEN="Government Service Tax">
    <TID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Amount>
      <CID>2</CID>
      <Value>148.00</Value>
    </Amount>
  </TL>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
      <ACD RBD="" ACCID="1" MCT="Super Sale Fare(AP)" INC="false" />
      <ATSID xsi:nil="true" />
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
      <ACD RBD="" ACCID="1" MCT="Super Sale Fare(AP)" INC="false" />
      <ATSID xsi:nil="true" />
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <RuleDetails>
    <TRS xsi:nil="true" />
    <PP xsi:nil="true" />
    <II xsi:nil="true" />
    <LTD xsi:nil="true" />
  </RuleDetails>
</AirFareInfo>
```

Please suggest how it can be done keeping performance in mind.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fully working example.

You told us, that performance matters, so **do not use scalar UDF!**

Try it like this (next time it's your job to [create a (**reduced!!!**) MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB;
GO
USE testDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE Booking(BookingID INT CONSTRAINT PK_Booking PRIMARY KEY
                    ,SomeBookingData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES(1,'Booking 1'),(2,'Booking 2');

CREATE TABLE BookingInfo(BookingID INT CONSTRAINT FK_BookingInfo_BookingID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Booking(BookingID)
                        ,SomeOtherInfo VARCHAR(100)
                        ,FareDetails XML);
INSERT INTO BookingInfo VALUES
 (1,'First row for ID=1, returns AP,AP'
 ,N'<AirFareInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IPFA="false">
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AP</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
</AirFareInfo>')
,(1,'Second row for ID=1, returns XY,MN'
 ,N'<AirFareInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IPFA="false">
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>XY</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>MN</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
</AirFareInfo>')
,(2,'row with ID=2, returns AA,BB'
 ,N'<AirFareInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IPFA="false">
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>AA</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
  <PTSDPFS>
    <PTSD IO="false">
      <FBC>BB</FBC>
    </PTSD>
  </PTSDPFS>
</AirFareInfo>');
GO
```

--This is the function. It returns `as table` and is fully inlined (no `BEGIN...END`!)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateBookingInfoCSV(@BookingID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ','+REPLACE(FareDetails.query(N'data(/AirFareInfo/PTSDPFS/PTSD/FBC)').value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),' ',',')
    FROM BookingInfo AS bi
    WHERE bi.BookingID=@BookingID
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') AS BookingInfoCSV;
GO
```

--**Hint** the trick with `XQuery data() function` will break, if your values contain blanks!

--The following `SELECT` calls all rows from `Booking`-table and gets the fitting details

```
SELECT b.BookingID
      ,b.SomeBookingData
      ,A.BookingInfoCSV 
FROM Booking AS b
OUTER APPLY dbo.CreateBookingInfoCSV(b.BookingID) AS A;
GO
```

--Clean up (**carefull with real data!**)

```
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE testDB;
```

--The result

```
BookingID   SomeBookingData BookingInfoCSV
1           Booking 1       AP,AP,XY,MN
2           Booking 2       AA,BB
```

Comment: Hey @Shnugo , 
this solution works fine , except when there is a space in  <FBC> ttribute value 
i.e if xml is coming like this  <FBC>AP </FBC>
we are getting the out put as AP,
if there are two nodes
AP,,AP,
Please correct.

Comment: If you do not have any spaces *within* the codes, you can just wrap the whole result with `REPLACE(A.BookingInfoCSV,',,',',')` to replace double comma with single comma. To be honest: This is a (good) hack, but it's a hack...

Comment: Hola @shnugo.. But if the value is (space after AP )<FBC>AP </FBC> we are getting the out put as AP,

Comment: @PiyushSing Well, it is not forbidden to do some thinking on your own... Either **append one extra unusual character**, then replace the comma with this unusal character and again the unusual character only. Or you check if the last character is a comma (`CASE WHEN ... RIGHT(...,1) ...`) and use `LEFT` with `LEN`-1... This should be rather easy...