# SQL Server : Issue in exists query replace with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, exists, sql-optimization

I am using the following code to fetch the report.

```
DECLARE @CountryID smallint = 100
DECLARE @UTCTDIM smallint = 330
DECLARE @MarketProfileID smallint = 2
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2017-01-03'
DECLARE @CustomerTypeID smallint = 1

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AirportList TABLE (ID bigint)
INSERT INTO @AirportList (ID)
SELECT
    DISTINCT Airport.ID
FROM
    Airport
    INNER JOIN CityList ON Airport.CityID = CityList.ID
    INNER JOIN CountryList ON CityList.CountryID = CountryList.ID
where
    CountryList.NameEN in ('San Marino','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Turkey','Ukraine','United Kingdom','Vatican CityList')

DECLARE @TempSales TABLE
(   
    [Type] varchar(50),
    [From] char(3),
    [To] char(3),
    [Tickets] bigint,
    [Average fare] decimal(18,3),
    [Net sale] decimal(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @TempSales
SELECT 
    [AirTrips].[NameEN] AS [Type],
    [Airport1].[IATACode] AS [From],
    [Airport2].[IATACode] AS [To],
    NULL,
    AVG(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[FareBaseAmount], 0)) + AVG(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[Taxes], 0)) AS [Average fare],
    SUM(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[AmountNetRemit], 0)) AS [Net sale]
FROM
    [BookingDetails] WITH (READPAST)
    INNER JOIN [Bookings] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.BookingFileID = BookingFile.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTrips] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.AirTripTypeID = AirTrips.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTraveler] WITH (READPAST) ON AirTraveler.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirOrigin] WITH (READPAST) ON AirOrigin.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport1] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport1].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] 
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport2] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport2].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID]
WHERE
    [Bookings].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 20, 22, 23) 
    AND [Bookings].[IsActive] = 1 
    AND [AirOrigin].[AirTripDirectionTypeID] = 1 
    AND (ISNULL([AirTraveler].[BaseAmountNetRemit], 0) + ISNULL([AirTraveler].[TaxesNetRemit], 0)) <> 0 
    AND [Bookings].[RemitDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND [BookingDetails].[MarketProfileID] = @MarketProfileID 
    AND [BookingDetails].[BookedForOrganizationID] IS NULL
    AND (
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport1].ID)
        OR
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport2].ID)
    )
GROUP BY
    [AirTrips].[NameEN],
    [Airport1].[IATACode],
    [Airport2].[IATACode]

INSERT INTO @TempSales
SELECT
    [AirTrips].[NameEN] AS [Type],
    [Airport1].[IATACode] AS [From],
    [Airport2].[IATACode] AS [To],
    COUNT(*) [Tickets],
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM
    [BookingDetails] WITH (READPAST)
    INNER JOIN [Bookings] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.BookingFileID = BookingFile.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTrips] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.AirTripTypeID = AirTrips.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTraveler] WITH (READPAST) ON AirTraveler.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirOrigin] WITH (READPAST) ON AirOrigin.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport1] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport1].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] 
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport2] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport2].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID] 
WHERE
    [Bookings].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 22, 23)
    AND [Bookings].[IsActive] = 1
    AND [AirOrigin].[AirTripDirectionTypeID] = 1
    AND (ISNULL([AirTraveler].[BaseAmountNetRemit], 0) + ISNULL([AirTraveler].[TaxesNetRemit], 0)) <> 0
    AND [Bookings].[RemitDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND [BookingDetails].[MarketProfileID] = @MarketProfileID 
    AND [BookingDetails].[BookedForOrganizationID] IS NULL
    AND (
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport1].ID)
        OR
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport2].ID)
    )
GROUP BY
    [AirTrips].[NameEN],
    [Airport1].[IATACode],
    [Airport2].[IATACode]

SELECT  
    [Type],
    [From],
    [To],
    COALESCE( SUM([Tickets]), 0) AS [Tickets],
    COALESCE( SUM([Average fare]), 0) AS [Average fare],
    COALESCE( SUM([Net sale]), 0) AS [Net sale]
FROM 
    @TempSales
GROUP BY
    [Type],
    [From],
    [To]
ORDER BY 
    [Tickets] DESC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [From] ASC,
    [To] ASC
```

I have million records in the database.
For small records (2,3) days , it is working fine.
But for large records (10 days) , I am getting the resource locked/time out error.

I found one issue is with following code :

```
AND (
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport1].ID)
        OR
        EXISTS (SELECT A.ID FROM @AirportList A WHERE A.ID = [Airport2].ID)
    )
```

If i remove this code.I am not facing much issue.
Please help me to find an alternate way to write this code or optmize it

Comment: I don't think it could solve your problem, but I think you can rewrite your condition as `EXISTS (
   SELECT A.ID
   FROM @AirportList A
   WHERE A.ID IN (Airport1.ID, Airport2.ID)
   )`
   
and try again.
Can you post explain plan?

Comment: Have you tried to make INNER JOIN to @AirportList table where A.ID will be EITHER equal to [Airport1].ID OR [Airport2].ID ??

Comment: @etsa : Not making any difference

Comment: @ Abdullah Dibas : Could you please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add primary key to the temp table

```
DECLARE @AirportList TABLE (ID bigint primary key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @CountryID smallint = 100
    DECLARE @UTCTDIM smallint = 330
    DECLARE @MarketProfileID smallint = 2
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017-01-01'
    DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2017-01-03'
    DECLARE @CustomerTypeID smallint = 1

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @AirportList TABLE (ID bigint)
    INSERT INTO @AirportList (ID)
    SELECT
       DISTINCT Airport.ID
    FROM
      Airport
    INNER JOIN CityList ON Airport.CityID = CityList.ID
    INNER JOIN CountryList ON CityList.CountryID = CountryList.ID
    where
       CountryList.NameEN in ('San   Marino','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Turkey','Ukraine','United Kingdom','Vatican CityList')

DECLARE @TempSales TABLE
(   
    [Type] varchar(50),
    [From] char(3),
    [To] char(3),
    [Tickets] bigint,
    [Average fare] decimal(18,3),
    [Net sale] decimal(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @TempSales
SELECT 
    [AirTrips].[NameEN] AS [Type],
    [Airport1].[IATACode] AS [From],
    [Airport2].[IATACode] AS [To],
    NULL,
    AVG(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[FareBaseAmount], 0)) + AVG(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[Taxes], 0)) AS [Average fare],
    SUM(ISNULL([AirTraveler].[AmountNetRemit], 0)) AS [Net sale]
FROM
    [BookingDetails] WITH (READPAST)
    INNER JOIN [Bookings] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.BookingFileID = BookingFile.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTrips] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.AirTripTypeID = AirTrips.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTraveler] WITH (READPAST) ON AirTraveler.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirOrigin] WITH (READPAST) ON AirOrigin.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport1] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport1].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] 
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport2] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport2].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID]
    INNER JOIN @AirportList AS A ON  A.ID = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] OR A.ID = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID] 
WHERE
    [Bookings].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 20, 22, 23) 
    AND [Bookings].[IsActive] = 1 
    AND [AirOrigin].[AirTripDirectionTypeID] = 1 
    AND (ISNULL([AirTraveler].[BaseAmountNetRemit], 0) + ISNULL([AirTraveler].[TaxesNetRemit], 0)) <> 0 
    AND [Bookings].[RemitDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND [BookingDetails].[MarketProfileID] = @MarketProfileID 
    AND [BookingDetails].[BookedForOrganizationID] IS NULL
GROUP BY
    [AirTrips].[NameEN],
    [Airport1].[IATACode],
    [Airport2].[IATACode]

INSERT INTO @TempSales
SELECT
    [AirTrips].[NameEN] AS [Type],
    [Airport1].[IATACode] AS [From],
    [Airport2].[IATACode] AS [To],
    COUNT(*) [Tickets],
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM
    [BookingDetails] WITH (READPAST)
    INNER JOIN [Bookings] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.BookingFileID = BookingFile.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTrips] WITH (READPAST) ON Booking.AirTripTypeID = AirTrips.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirTraveler] WITH (READPAST) ON AirTraveler.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [AirOrigin] WITH (READPAST) ON AirOrigin.BookingID = Booking.ID
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport1] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport1].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] 
    INNER JOIN [Airport] AS [Airport2] WITH (READPAST) ON [Airport2].[ID] = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID] 
    INNER JOIN @AirportList AS A ON  A.ID = [AirOrigin].[DepartureAirportID] OR A.ID = [AirOrigin].[ArrivalAirportID] 
WHERE
    [Bookings].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 22, 23)
    AND [Bookings].[IsActive] = 1
    AND [AirOrigin].[AirTripDirectionTypeID] = 1
    AND (ISNULL([AirTraveler].[BaseAmountNetRemit], 0) + ISNULL([AirTraveler].[TaxesNetRemit], 0)) <> 0
    AND [Bookings].[RemitDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND [BookingDetails].[MarketProfileID] = @MarketProfileID 
    AND [BookingDetails].[BookedForOrganizationID] IS NULL
GROUP BY
    [AirTrips].[NameEN],
    [Airport1].[IATACode],
    [Airport2].[IATACode]

SELECT  
    [Type],
    [From],
    [To],
    COALESCE( SUM([Tickets]), 0) AS [Tickets],
    COALESCE( SUM([Average fare]), 0) AS [Average fare],
    COALESCE( SUM([Net sale]), 0) AS [Net sale]
FROM 
    @TempSales
GROUP BY
    [Type],
    [From],
    [To]
ORDER BY 
    [Tickets] DESC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [From] ASC,
    [To] ASC
```

Comment: It went into the infinite loop.